# How to set default value in Eureka-Form

Tags: eureka-forms

I am creating a series of ImageCheckRows as a SelectableSection, and I would like to set some default values.  Essentially each row returns a true/false value, so somewhere there should be a simply method of setting true or false on each row.  I tried the row.value but this requires a 'String?'

```
currentSection! <<< ImageCheckRow<String> { row in
   row.tag = "\(tagname)_\(optionKey)"
   row.title = optionValue as? String
   row.selectableValue = optionKey as? String

   if let dvkey = optionKey as? String {
      print("dvkey = \(dvkey)")
      if let _ = defaultValues?.value(forKey: dvkey) {
         print("we found dvkey in the defaultValues dict - try row.select")
         row.value = true
      }
   }

}.cellSetup { cell, _ in
   cell.trueImage = UIImage(named: imageChecked)!
   cell.falseImage = UIImage(named: imageUnchecked)!
}
```

I also tried using the function:

```
row.select()
```

But this didn't work either.
Then I tried moving it to the cellSetup, but this didn't work either.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worked it out myself...

```
row.value = optionKeyValue as? String
```

This is a radio button style control, and as I create the row with the default radio button I set the value to the key, however it must be a string representation, even if it is numeric. Who would have guessed!

My first thought was that the radio button control is checked/unchecked, hence it should really be a true/false value.

My second thought was that the radio button control default value would be set against the group, which is a more logical place to set or change the value.

Wrong on both counts.